# Pandas : filter column based on category and replace values from another data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, join, pandas-groupby, inner-join

I have two data frames consist of 3 columns
dataframe1  has 2 columns & dataframe2  has 1 column

dataframe 1

```
   name category
1  abc   fruit
2  def   animal
3  cfg    nan
4  abc   fruit
5  def   animal
6  cfg    nan
7  abc   fruit
8  def   animal
9  cfg    nan
10 abc   fruit
11 def   animal
12 cfg    nan
```

data frame 2

```
  actual_cat
1 plant
2 plant
3 plant
4 plant
```

now the final output dataframe should be

```
  name category
1 abc   fruit
2 def   animal
3 cfg    **PLANT**
4 abc   fruit
5 def   animal
6 cfg    **PLANT**
7 abc   fruit
8 def   animal
9 cfg    **PLANT**
10 abc   fruit
11 def   animal
12 cfg    **PLANT**
```

i tried using filter condition like

```py
data.loc(data(['name']=='cfg') & data2['actual])
```

but am facing issues. kindly need help

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the dataframes in text form (so we can copy-paste them)?

Comment: @AndrejKesely sure will do it right now thanks for your valuable reply

Comment: @AndrejKesely just now updated data could you check please

Comment: Do you want to fill all `cfg` values with values from `df2`? are the number of `df2` values the same as number of `cfg` values from `df1`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes actually name , category columns are in 3 data frames , but name column of cfg & "category" column has null values because that column name values are in different column so i want to join this "plant" values to cfg==plant

Answer (score 1):

If dataframe 2 matches the null values length of dataframe 1 exactly, you can do something like this:

```
counter = 0 
for i in data[data["category"].isnull()].index:
    data.at[i, "category"] = data2["actual_cat"][counter]
    counter+=1
```

This loops through the indices of dataframe 1 where the values are `NaN`, then reassigns the value of that specific index on column `category` to dataframe 2's column `actual_cat` and index `counter` which is iterated through each loop. If you have more `NaN` values then you do values in dataframe 2 then you will run into an error.

Based on your example, you might be able to get away with:

```
data.fillna("plant", inplace=True)
```

This will fill all your missing values from dataframe 1 to "plant"